# add LSTM/GRU to BERT embeddings in keras tensorflow

Tags: lstm, word-embedding, tf.keras

I am experimenting with BERT embeddings following this code https://github.com/strongio/keras-bert/blob/master/keras-bert.py

These are the important bits of the code (lines 265-267):

```
bert_output = BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=3)(bert_inputs)
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(bert_output)
pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(dense)
```

I want to add a GRU between BertLayer and the Dense layer

```
bert_output = BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=3)(bert_inputs)
gru_out = tf.keras.layers.GRU(100, activation='sigmoid')(bert_output)
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(gru_out)
pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(dense)
```

but I get this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`.

I am not entirely sure how to address this problem. Do I need to reshape `bert_output` or do I need to create an `Embedding` layer that the `GRU` can handle?

Comment: Any luck on how to use that? [daria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4304541/daria?tab=profile)

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same error, the solution to this is

```py
embedding_size = 768

bert_output = BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=3)(bert_inputs)
# Reshape bert_output before passing it the GRU
bert_output_ = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((max_seq_length, embedding_size))(bert_output)

gru_out = tf.keras.layers.GRU(100, activation='sigmoid')(bert_output_)
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(gru_out)
pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(dense)
```

I hope it works, you can refer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607787/bert-embeddings-layer-raises-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-non) if needed