# Getting sequence output from BERT encoder (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model

I am attempting to fine-tune BERT in tensorflow following this [official guide](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/colab/fine_tuning_bert.ipynb) with the goal of feeding the output further into LSTM/GRU. I am able to run the fine-tuning but the output shapes I am getting from the `bert_encoder` are *[num_samples, hidden_units]* and *[num_samples, 1, 768]*. I believe these are pooled and sequence outputs respectively but I am confused why the sequence output is not *[num_samples, max_seq_length, hidden_units]*.

Running this code after replacing `bert_classifier` with `bert_encoder` on compile and fit:

```
bert_encoder([glue_train["input_word_ids"][0:10],
              glue_train["input_mask"][0:10],
              glue_train["input_type_ids"][0:10]])
```

produces:

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 1, 768), dtype=float32, numpy= ...>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 768), dtype=float32, numpy= ...>]
```

Since I am passing to sequence models, I need to get the sequence output but I keep getting only 1 shape for the sequence length. I've been trying to understand why but can't find anything on it. Any help and clarifications would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The problem occurs because, BERT model uses outputs of CLS token with Logistic Regression layer for classification. Thus, tough [num_samples, seq_len , hidden_size] should be the possible output, it produces  [num_samples, 1 , hidden_size] because of CLS token only. The hidden size of each token is 768. You can still modify the BERT_encoder function to return the complete sequence.

Comment: Please check if this post is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607787/bert-embedding-layer-raises-type-error-unsupported-operand-types-for-non/58769570#58769570